# Click To Call, mailto: and gmaps links won't activate

Tags: javascript, drupal, mobile-safari, mobile-website

First, as always, thanks in advance for the help!

I'm building a mobile site using drupal and having a very weird problem.  My front page is in an accordion, and the last tab, let's talk the mailto, clicktocall and gmaps links will not activate.  The accordion is built with a view, and I've tried everything up to the point of hacking the view and using  to print out the marked up content.  But I think it has something to do with the accordion JS because the links will not activate.  However, if I go to the actual page /lets-talk, and look at it, the links work just fine.

Here are the two urls:
http://m.cbdmarketing.com 
and 
http://m.cbdmarketing.com/lets-talk;

You'd have to hit with an iphone emulator, or a UA switcher.

And here's the marked up html:

```
<div class="content"><p><a target="_blank" href="http://maps.google.com/maps?f=q&amp;source=s_q&amp;hl=en&amp;geocode=&amp;q=54+w.+hubbard+chicago&amp;aq=&amp;sll=37.0625,-95.677068&amp;sspn=33.435463,74.091797&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;hq=&amp;hnear=54+W+Hubbard+St,+Chicago,+Cook,+Illinois+60654&amp;t=h&amp;z=16">54 W. Hubbard Street Concourse Level East<br />Chicago, IL 60654</a><br />+1 (312) 661-1050</p><p>Prospective clients, please contact:<br />Doug Davila <a href="mailto:ddavila@cbdmarketing.com">ddavila@cbdmarketing.com</a><br />+1 (312) 661-1050  x424</p><p>For career opportunities, send resume to: <a href="mailto:hr@cbdmarketing.com">hr@cbdmarketing.com</a></p></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't check it with an iPhone or UA Switcher, but when I view the source of the front page you linked to, it's not including *ANY* .js files. Make sure the  section of your page.tpl.php includes:

```
<?php print $scripts ?>
```